# Can a chrome extension read data from the local storage?

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension

If a chrome-extension requests the permission "Read and modify all your data on all websites you visit", can it then read data from the local storage of one of these visited sites?

I'm asking this because I know of some websites which store authentication tokens in the local storage. If the extension can access the token, it would be frightfully easy to harvest access tokens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is Yes. Content script injected by an extension has full access to `localStorage` for the site.

Comment: note that this is not surprising or new. extensions are meant to have this access and could also get tokens by snooping network traffic. by design.